# Showing "See results about" on google knowledge graph

Tags: seo, google-knowledge-graph

My client as a Wikipedia and Wikidata page and have started to work on getting a  google knowledge graph for the client.

Now, after a week on various schema tagging a "See results about" on the right panel now appears when someone googles the entity name in google.

[image]

Yet this is not the full graph and to obtain the full graph, a user still needs to click on the link above in order to obtain this:
[image]

So my point is that I need the full graph to be obtain straight from the time when the entity is searched in Googlem without having to click first on a disambiguity link.

For the avoidance of doubt, the entity has a unique Name, meaning, no one else has the same, so I am not sure where there is still ambiguity.

Happy to hear your thoughts.

Cheers and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<Tittle>"P@sha Award winner 2016 Multi-biz Services"</Tittle>
<meta name="keyword" content="P@sha ICT Award Winner Abdul Haseeb. Bringing together local tech stars on a single platform, the Awards ceremony lauded innovation and excellence in the Pakistan." >
<meta name="description" content="Multi-Biz services provide e-solutions for the future needs of YOUR Business. At Multi Biz Services our dedicated team works in conjunction with our clients towards a common goal business growth. We aim to become trusted and well-known brand." >
<meta name="description" content="Multi-biz Services, Web developer in pakistan, web developer in Peshawar Multibiz Services, Achieved pasha award in 2016 | Abdul Haseeb" >
<meta name="keywords" content="http://www.multibizservices.com/,KPIT Board Top Company, Web developer in Pakistan, Web developer in Peshawar | Multibiz services, Online Shop Developer in Peshawar | Multibiz Services, TOP IT Company in pakistan| Multibiz Services, Pasha Award winner Abdul Haseeb" >
```